# CSS didn't apply to a form constructed by php

Tags: php, html, css

I've constructed a form using php and echo this form in html page. I've defined a CSS for the html page however it is not working. I tried to save the source of the generated html page to a separate file with extension .html and when loaded, the CSS works! . I don't know what is wrong

THIS IS AN UPDATE
The problem is solved. I put the absolute path of the CSS file instead. and it seems this issue happened (CSS was not found) because I'm using url rewriting to load the php file. the question now is: **how do I troubleshoot such issues?**

**how do I know that the browser/server cannot find the CSS file?**

ANOTHER UPDATE:

I found this link is very helpful
[Steps to troubleshoot CSS problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9754330/steps-to-troubleshoot-css-problems)

Here is the php code

```
<?php
require_once 'constants.php';
$titles = get_title(FILE_NAME);
$htmlForm .= '<form method="post" action=' . '"' . htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) . '"' . '><fieldset><legend>This is my form</legend>';
for ($i = 0; $i < count($titles); $i++) {
    $htmlForm .= '<p><label for="' . $titles[$i] . '">' . $titles[$i] . '</label><input type="text" id="' . $titles[$i] . '" value="' . $line[$i] . '"/></p>';
}
$htmlForm .= '<input type="hidden" name="mode" value="' . $_GET['mode'] . '">';
$htmlForm .= '<p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></p></fieldset></form>';
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php echo $htmlForm; ?>
        <input name="newThread" type="button" value="Back to List View" onclick="window.location.href='/hshahin/cs5774/02-Project2/index';"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the CSS script.

```
.submit input {
    margin-left: 4.5em;
    color: #000;
    background: #ffa20f;
    border: 2px outset #d7b9c9
}
input {
    color: #781351;
    background: #fee3ad;
    border: 1px solid #781351
}
fieldset {
    border: 1px solid #781351;
    width: 20em
}
legend {
    color: #fff;
    background: #ffa20c;
    border: 1px solid #781351;
    padding: 2px 6px
}
```

Comment: Have you added stylesheet to your form?

Comment: PHP has nothing to do with this. Removing it will clearify your question!

Comment: Try CTRL+SHIFT+R . It might be cache issue.

Comment: I don't think it will fix it, but as a note, it is faster to refer to input as .submit>input. Better yet, if you don't plan on having multiple inputs under the .submit class (which can cause a pain if you decide to create another element of class submit with different properties), use id, call it with #, and attach it directly to the submit button, like #submit. Your choice but definitely would help you organize for the future.

Comment: If you are doing any url rewriting, it is safer to use an absolute path for the assets (relative to the web-server root) like `href="/default.css"`. Safer in the sense of avoiding potential not-found problems...

Comment: default.css is in the same location as the php file. when I moved the actual CSS to the php file it works!. but it is not working when i store it externally and use <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css">

Comment: @ jeroen , thanks for comments. this solves the problem. Actually yes I'm using url rewriting BUT my question is: how to trouble shoot such issues? thx

Answer (score 2):

Check the path for your style.css file. Is it located in the same location as the PHP file?
What happens if you don't include the stylesheet, but instead type in the actual CSS?

Comment: default.css is in the same location as the php file. when I moved the actual CSS to the php file it works!. but it is not working when i store it externally and use <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css">

Answer (score 0):

clear your browser cache. The browser automatically caches the style sheet for quicker response time.

Comment: shift f5 will reload all assets on most browsers also

Answer (score 0):

Use it and tell me how it goes. If it works, then path of your style sheet is wrong.

```
<?php
require_once 'constants.php';
$titles = get_title(FILE_NAME);
$htmlForm .= '<form method="post" action=' . '"' . htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) . '"' . '><fieldset><legend>This is my form</legend>';
for ($i = 0; $i < count($titles); $i++) {
    $htmlForm .= '<p><label for="' . $titles[$i] . '">' . $titles[$i] . '</label><input type="text" id="' . $titles[$i] . '" value="' . $line[$i] . '"/></p>';
}
$htmlForm .= '<input type="hidden" name="mode" value="' . $_GET['mode'] . '">';
$htmlForm .= '<p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></p></fieldset></form>';
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
.submit input {
    margin-left: 4.5em;
    color: #000;
    background: #ffa20f;
    border: 2px outset #d7b9c9
}
input {
    color: #781351;
    background: #fee3ad;
    border: 1px solid #781351
}
fieldset {
    border: 1px solid #781351;
    width: 20em
}
legend {
    color: #fff;
    background: #ffa20c;
    border: 1px solid #781351;
    padding: 2px 6px
}
</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php echo $htmlForm; ?>
        <input name="newThread" type="button" value="Back to List View" onclick="window.location.href='/hshahin/cs5774/02-Project2/index';"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: default.css is in the same location as the php file. when I moved the actual CSS to the php file it works!. but it is not working when i store it externally and use <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css">

Answer (score 0):

Are the styles not applying to anything or only the parts that are echoed out by PHP? Perhaps the stylesheet isn't loading, try refreshing the page without cache.

Comment: I tried to save the html page generated out of the php script to a separate html file called test.html. And the CSS worked correctly when the test.html file loaded!

Comment: Perhaps you require a forward slash in the link tag: `<link />`

Comment: The problem is solved. I put the absolute path of the CSS file instead. and it seems this issue happened (CSS was not found) because I'm using url rewriting to load the php file. the question now is: how do I troubleshoot such issues?

how do I know that the browser/server cannot find the CSS file?

Comment: In Google chrome, you can open the developer tab (F12) and check to see if the CSS file is found in the "sources" tab. I'm sure other browsers have something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions:
Instead of

```
<?php
require_once 'constants.php';
$titles = get_title(FILE_NAME);
$htmlForm .= '<form method="post" action=' . '"' . htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) . '"' . '><fieldset><legend>This is my form</legend>';
for ($i = 0; $i < count($titles); $i++) {
    $htmlForm .= '<p><label for="' . $titles[$i] . '">' . $titles[$i] . '</label><input type="text" id="' . $titles[$i] . '" value="' . $line[$i] . '"/></p>';
}
$htmlForm .= '<input type="hidden" name="mode" value="' . $_GET['mode'] . '">';
$htmlForm .= '<p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></p></fieldset></form>';
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php echo $htmlForm; ?>
        <input name="newThread" type="button" value="Back to List View" onclick="window.location.href='/hshahin/cs5774/02-Project2/index';"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Try

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css">
        </head>
        <body>
    <?php
    require_once 'constants.php';
    $titles = get_title(FILE_NAME);
    $htmlForm .= '<form method="post" action=' . '"' . htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) . '"' . '><fieldset><legend>This is my form</legend>';
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($titles); $i++) {
        $htmlForm .= '<p><label for="' . $titles[$i] . '">' . $titles[$i] . '</label><input type="text" id="' . $titles[$i] . '" value="' . $line[$i] . '"/></p>';
    }
    $htmlForm .= '<input type="hidden" name="mode" value="' . $_GET['mode'] . '">';
    $htmlForm .= '<p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></p></fieldset></form>';
    ?>
 <?php echo $htmlForm; ?>
        <input name="newThread" type="button" value="Back to List View" onclick="window.location.href='/hshahin/cs5774/02-Project2/index';"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Also Instead of

```
<?php
require_once 'constants.php';
$titles = get_title(FILE_NAME);
$htmlForm .= '<form method="post" action=' . '"' . htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) . '"' . '><fieldset><legend>This is my form</legend>';
for ($i = 0; $i < count($titles); $i++) {
    $htmlForm .= '<p><label for="' . $titles[$i] . '">' . $titles[$i] . '</label><input type="text" id="' . $titles[$i] . '" value="' . $line[$i] . '"/></p>';
}
$htmlForm .= '<input type="hidden" name="mode" value="' . $_GET['mode'] . '">';
$htmlForm .= '<p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></p></fieldset></form>';
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php echo $htmlForm; ?>
        <input name="newThread" type="button" value="Back to List View" onclick="window.location.href='/hshahin/cs5774/02-Project2/index';"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

TRY

```
<?
require_once 'constants.php';
$titles = get_title(FILE_NAME);
$htmlForm .= '<form method="post" action=' . '"' . htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) . '"' . '><fieldset><legend>This is my form</legend>';
for ($i = 0; $i < count($titles); $i++) {
    $htmlForm .= '<p><label for="' . $titles[$i] . '">' . $titles[$i] . '</label><input type="text" id="' . $titles[$i] . '" value="' . $line[$i] . '"/></p>';
}
$htmlForm .= '<input type="hidden" name="mode" value="' . $_GET['mode'] . '">';
$htmlForm .= '<p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></p></fieldset></form>';
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php echo $htmlForm; ?>
        <input name="newThread" type="button" value="Back to List View" onclick="window.location.href='/hshahin/cs5774/02-Project2/index';"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. I put the absolute path of the CSS file instead. and it seems this issue happened (CSS was not found) because I'm using url rewriting to load the php file.

I found this link is very helpful: [Steps to troubleshoot CSS problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9754330/steps-to-troubleshoot-css-problems)